# how to call a javascript class function from a another file in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to call and use class 1 getDescription function to class2. I tried using require and calling the function but can get it. Thanks. I wanted to reuse the function from class1

## Class 1

```
exports.Class1 = class Class1 {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
    this.utils = options.utils;
  }

  getDescription(request) {
    if (request.description) {
      return request.description;
    }

    if (!request.respondent) {
      return 'No description';
    }

    if (request.respondent.employee) {
      return request.respondent.employee.name;
    }

    return `${request.respondent.firstName} ${request.respondent.lastName}`;
  }


};
```

## class2

```
const Class1  = require('../Class1');

exports.Class2 = class Class2 {
  constructor(options) {
    this.options = options || {};
    this.utils = options.utils;
  }
  const description = Class1.getDescription()
.....
```

Comment: Are you forgetting about the parameter to the getDescription(request) function? Might also want to get an instance of the class

Comment: I think you need to instantiate Class1 inside the Class2 module.

Comment: A primer on javascript class instantiation: https://medium.com/@ryuta_udo/define-class-instantiation-with-javascript-es6-8217d6499fae

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you forgetting about the parameter of the `getDescription(request)` function?

You might also want to instantiate the class, i.e. `let myClass1Obj = new Class1(...)` then call `myClass1Obj.getDescription(request)`

Also, it should be `const Class1  = require('../Class1').Class1;` in your case.

Comment: Try `const Class1  = require('../Class1').Class1;`